# React app stopped reporting errors in the console such as usage of undefined variables, silently fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console.log

I'm not sure what happened over the course of development, but I'm using React 0.13 with Webpack, and whenever I attempt to use an undefined variable, it fails to execute past that point. For example, even a simple `console.log(anundefinedvariable);` fails to execute (and no lines after that get run.) Nothing shows in the console, which makes it very difficult to debug.

I don't know where to begin to solve the issue. Where should I start?

Edit: actually now that I think about it, I might have done an `npm update` command -- maybe this somehow introduced this problem. Not sure what to do, still.

Edit2: My package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "docs"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js 'test/**/*.@(js|jsx)'"
  },
  "author": "Name",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-object-assign": "^1.2.1",
    "firebase": "^2.2.9",
    "fireproof": "^3.0.3",
    "immutable": "^3.7.5",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "q": "^1.4.1",
    "react": "^0.13.3",
    "react-redux": "^2.1.2",
    "react-router": "^1.0.0-rc1",
    "redux": "^3.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^5.8.24",
    "babel-loader": "^5.3.2",
    "chai": "^3.3.0",
    "chai-immutable": "^1.3.0",
    "jsdom": "^3.1.2",
    "mocha": "^2.3.3",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.11.0"
  }
}
```

My webpack config:

var webpack = require('webpack');

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/js/index.jsx'
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'react-hot!babel?plugins=babel-plugin-object-assign'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ["src/js/", "web_modules", "node_modules"],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Comment: The steps for this is 1) Start removing all code and dependencies until you get it working again. 2) Add back 1 dependency and small pieces of code until it stops working. 3) For future reference always use `npm shrinkwrap` in order to lockdown dependencies. 4) Use GIT or any other VCS.

Comment: Can you show us your package.json, and, the process you are using to build the code? My guess is you have a non-console rule turned on in the build process and that's killing your builds.

Comment: @limelights how is it even possible to suppress these errors? By overriding the console command?

Comment: It's hard to know what you mean by suppress, your question indicates that you're trying to use a undefined variable but you don't say where which makes it super hard for us to guess. I think the best course of action would be either to put the project on git so I can help you further by checking it out myself or to follow the steps I wrote above. As for suppressing the errors there are libraries that can hijack the console and swallow the output.

Comment: @limelights whenever I used one in the past, it always logged it to the console. Now that it's not logging there, I'm calling it "suppressed". I'll try and dig some more tomorrow before bothering you with my code base -- but thank you!

Comment: @Blossoming_Flower hey did you found out what is happening? I have the same problem now.

Comment: @Blossoming_Flower I found my problem.. is promises eating the errors.